# Remove any text between two parameters not working properly

Tags: sed

I need to remove any data between , and (  and the "," along with it.

I'm currently using the below command.

```
sed -i '/,/,/(/{//!d;s/ ,$//}' test1.txt
```

**cat test1.txt**

> CREATE SET TABLE EDW_EXTRC_TAB.AVER_MED_CLM_HDR_EXTRC
>
> ,NO FALLBACK ,
>        NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
>        NO AFTER JOURNAL,
>        CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
>        DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
>
> (
>         EXTRC_RUN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,

**Current Output**

> CREATE SET TABLE EDW_EXTRC_TAB.AVER_MED_CLM_HDR_EXTRC
>
> ,NO FALLBACK  (
>         EXTRC_RUN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,

**Expected Output:**

> CREATE SET TABLE EDW_EXTRC_TAB.AVER_MED_CLM_HDR_EXTRC
>
> (
>         EXTRC_RUN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,

What is wrong here ?
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure you post correct, reproducible examples here.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

-- GNU ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -z 's/,[^(]*//' test1.txt
```

---

-- GNU ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -v RS= '{ sub(/,[^(]+/,"",$0) }1' test1.txt
```

---

The output:

```
CREATE SET TABLE EDW_EXTRC_TAB.AVER_MED_CLM_HDR_EXTRC
( EXTRC_RUN_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Says "sed: invalid option -- 'z'".
Am i not having GNU sed then ?

Comment: Ignoring -z and running the command is only deleting the comma "," alone and not any data in between.

Comment: @lfc_07, `-z` option is crucial in this GNU sed approach. Do you have `gawk` installed?

Comment: Yes, gnu awk 3.1.7 version to be precise.

Comment: Any suggestions in gawk?

Comment: Awesome.Just one thing, dont know if i had mentioned it.
I need it to work for just the first occurence and not recursively.

Comment: Any suggestion for just the first occurence alone?